# Function returns temporary sheet

Tags: excel, vba

is this possible to create a function that returns temporary sheet?
Let's say I have got Sub as follow

```
Sub My_Sub()

  Dim harm As Worksheet
  Set harm = Sheets("my_sheet")
  
  Dim lastRow As Long, arr
    
  lastRow = harm.Range("A" & harm.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
  arr = harm.Range("T2:V" & lastRow).Value     
        
  MsgBox arr(2,5)+1
End Sub
```

Right now I'm working on `harm = Sheets("my_sheet")` and it loads whole sheet. Now I want to select part of that sheet and do the same operations so I wanted to write a function that will create temporary sheet, return it so in `My_Sub` I would have `Set harm = ReturnSheet()`.

Is it possible? I want to load pseudo sheet from function, so I don't need to change anything in `My_Sub` (I mean those Ranges with column letter indexes).

```
Function ReturnSheet() As Worksheet

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Set Rng = Selection
  
    lastRow = Selection.Rows.Count
    lastCol = Selection.Columns.Count
     
    ReturnSheet.Range("A2").Resize(lastRow, lastCol).Value = Rng
End Function
```

Right now I'm getting `Object variable or with block variable not set` at `ReturnSheet.Range("A2").Resize(lastRow, lastCol).Value = Rng`

Comment: Most likely what you want is a separate function that works with `Range`s, not a `Worksheet`. Note that a `Worksheet` always has the same number of rows.

Comment: If you really need a sheet (`Object`) you should use `Set ReturnSheet  = Rng.Parent`.  And use it in the `Sub` as `Set harm = ReturnSheet`. To return a sheet from selection. The selection sizes does not matter. But the above comment supposition can be taken in consideration, since your question is not so clear. Can you give an example in terms of: "Selecting a range "A2:D4" and calling the function it the function should return `...`.

Comment: And, if you want the function returning the range of selected cells, you should use: `Set ReturnSheet = Rng`. and function to be defined as `Function ReturnSheet() As Range`. But nothing in `My_Sub` looks to try using such a function...

Comment: @FaneDuru my Sub is transforming whole sheet right now, but because my data is expanding I want to call Sub only on new rows. But because in Sub i have columns as "A", "B" i can't work on array so i though the easiest way to pass only selected rows to `My_Sub` was by creating subsheet of my main sheet (same structure, but only selected rows) and changing only `Set harm = Sheets("my_sheet")` into `Set harm = ReturnSheet()`. Because I have multiple subs that I have to run i wanted to use function that will return wanted subsheet in to `Set harm = `

Comment: This does not mean to return a sheet! The concept of "creating subsheet of my main sheet (same structure, but only selected rows)" does not exist. You are talking about a `Range`. Declaring `harm` as a sheet and trying to return a range will never work. If from your question/code will be able to understand **what you really want" I can come with some suggestions. You do not even call the function to see/deduce what you expect. But the strange idea to baptize a range as a sheet is not something possible only because you are its godfather...

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not familiar with vba and datatypes/methods. Right now `My_Sub` works on whole sheet. I want it to work just on selected (for example with `Selection` method) rows (i select them in excel) but still want it to "start" from second row (imitate headings - `My_Sub` loads data from second row) and use letters "A", "B", (...) to iterate columns

Comment: Then you need Function returning a range. I cannot show you here how to build and use it. I will place an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the next `Function`. It returns a range meaning the selected cells without their first row:

```
Function ReturnRange(Optional boolAllRange As Boolean = False) As Range
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Selection
    If rng.rows.count = 1 Then Exit Function
    If boolAllRange Then
        Set ReturnRange = rng
    Else
        Set ReturnRange = rng.Offset(1).Resize(rng.rows.count - 1, rng.Columns.count)
    End If
End Function
```

You can test it using the next `Sub`:

```
Sub testReturnRange()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ReturnRange       'eliminating the header
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then Debug.Print rng.Address
    Set rng = ReturnRange(True) 'header inclusive...
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then Debug.Print rng.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: can I somehow modify it so the ReturnRange would return whole Selection (so without that offset(1)) + blank row at the top? Smth like `rng = Selection`, `rng = [BlankRow, rng]` so the final rng would be size `(Selection.Rows +1, Selection.Cols)`?

Comment: @Saguro It is possible, of course, but it looks not having any meaning. Why not using `Selection` directly...? OK. I will adapt the above code to return for both cases. I will create an `Optional` `Boolean` variable and you call the function without it, it will return as it does now. If you will call it as `Set rng = ReturnRange(True)`, it will return the whole selected range... Should it be OK for you?

Comment: @Saguro OK, adapted the function and the testing `Sub`. Please, test it and send some feedback...

Comment: In my Subs i have `returned_range.Range("K2:K" & lastRow).Value` and because I'm using that Sub for Selection but also for whole Sheet (the Sheet has headings, thats why I'm starting from 2nd row) it would be great if I could somehow append blank row just to skip him. Now i changed it to `ReturnRange = rng.Offset(-1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count + 1, rng.Columns.Count)` and it works, but appending blank row would be more... safe than selecting additional row and skipping it

Comment: @Saguro I cannot get you, but if you solve it, good for you! This is the learning way...